# Round Items in Column to nearest 5 if it's not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to select a column(of floats) in a dataframe and round all the values to the nearest 5 but only if the value is not NaN, which got me to this

```
df["velocity"].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == None else 5 * round(float(x)/5))
```

However, upon execution, I get this error

**ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer**

Answer (score 0):

Here is vectorized pandas version instead loop apply solution with [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html), last replace `None` or missing values to `0`:

```
(5 * df["velocity"].astype(float) / 5).round()).fillna(0)
```

Or:

```
df["velocity"].astype(float).div(5).round().mul(5).fillna(0)
```